# Почему TryParse работает не так как в C#

Tags: powershell

У меня есть такой код

```
[bool] Read ([TextReader]$i)
{
  [string]$text = $i.ReadLine();
  [string[]]$numbers = $text.Split('.');
  if ($numbers.Length -eq 4)
  {

    for ([int]$j = 0; $j -lt $numbers.Length;++ $j)
    {
      if (-not [byte]::TryParse($numbers[$j],[ref]$null))
      {
        return $false;
      }
      $this.data[$j] = [byte]::Parse($numbers[$j]);
    }
    return $true;
  }
  return $false;
}
```

Он работает, но почему не работает так

```
[bool] Read ([TextReader]$i)
{
  [string]$text = $i.ReadLine();
  [string[]]$numbers = $text.Split('.');
  if ($numbers.Length -eq 4)
  {

    for ([int]$j = 0; $j -lt $numbers.Length;++ $j)
    {
      if (-not [byte]::TryParse($numbers[$j],[ref]$this.data[$j]))
      {
        return $false;
      }
    }
    return $true;
  }
  return $false;
}
```

В C# TryParse меняет значение элемента массива, а в Powershell нет...
Что я упускаю?

Comment: PowerShell поддерживает ссылки `[ref]` только на переменные, но не на элементы массива.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо PetSerAl за ответ.
Изменил код так:

```
[bool] Read ([TextReader]$i)
{
  [string]$text = $i.ReadLine();
  [string[]]$numbers = $text.Split('.');
  if ($numbers.Length -eq 4)
  {
    for ([int]$j = 0; $j -lt $numbers.Length;++ $j)
    {
      [byte]$temp = 0;
      if (-not [byte]::TryParse($numbers[$j],[ref]$temp))
      {
        return $false;
      }
      $this.data[$j] = $temp;
    }
    return $true;
  }
  return $false;
}
```

Действительно, [ref] работает с переменными, но не работает с элементами массива. Буду Знать.